# Stopping all execution in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets with an Activate sub and one sheet without, let's call it Sheet0. I want to, when switching from Sheet0 to any other sheet, check that some condition is met on Sheet0 before switching and stay on Sheet0 if the condition isn't met. I added a Deactivate sub in Sheet0 so that, when switching sheets, the condition is checked and if is not met, pops a message box and ends execution before the Activate sub from the other sheet runs.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
If blnCondition Then
    MsgBox ("[...]")
    Me.Activate
    End
End If
End Sub
```

I used the End statement but for some reason, it doesn't work as I thought it would. It ends execution of the Deactivate sub but still jumps to the other sheet's Activate sub, same as if I used an Exit Sub. My understanding of the End statement was that it was the ultimate stopping method in VBA.

Is my comprehension of the End statement wrong or am I missing something else?

Comment: `Activate` will always fire regardless of what you do in the `Deactivate` handler, so instead of calling `End`, set a global flag which can be checked by the other `Activate` handlers, so they can send the user back to Sheet0.

Comment: @BigBen Activating a new sheet already triggered the events of deactivating Sheet0 and activating SheetX so changing EnableEvents mid event will not help unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah I misread your question.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, I guess I have no choice but to do it this way. Setting a Global flag is a good idea though, can check that in each Activate instead of the whole condition in every sheet.

Answer (score 3):

### Workbook SheetDeactivate Event

- [`Workbook.SheetDeactivate Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetdeactivate)
- Copy the following code into the `ThisWorkbook` module. `Sheet1` is the name of the worksheet that you don't want to deactivate if a condition is not met, in this example, if cell `A1` is empty.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        If IsEmpty(Sh.Range("A1")) Then
            Sh.Activate
            Sh.Range("A1").Select
            MsgBox "Cell 'A1' is empty.", vbCritical
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

### EDIT

- To prevent triggering the `Worksheet Activate` events of the remaining worksheets you will need to use a global (public) variable that will indicate if it is safe to activate them i.e. the condition in e.g. `Sheet1` is met. At the beginning of each of the `Worksheet Activate` event codes of the remaining worksheets, you will need to add an `If` statement checking for the value of the global variable.

**Relevant Sheet Module, e.g. `Sheet1` (code name, the name not in parentheses)**

```
Option Explicit

Public IsNotMet As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then
        IsNotMet = True
        Me.Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        MsgBox "Cell 'A1' is empty.", vbCritical
    Else
        IsNotMet = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**All Other Sheet Modules**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Sheet1.IsNotMet Then Exit Sub
    ' Your code, e.g.:
    MsgBox "Worksheet '" & Me.Name & "' activated.", vbinformation
End Sub
```

Comment: If there's processing in the other sheets' `Activate` event handlers which you want to skip if Sheet1 A1 is empty, you would need to set a global flag so they could exit early...

Comment: My code already took care of that, it still goes to the other sheet's Activate sub after.

Comment: If the `Sheet Activate` codes can be put (rewritten) into the `Workbook SheetActivate` event code of the `ThisWorkbook` module, you could declare a private boolean variable in the `ThisWorkbook` module. Is that an option or are the codes not related? Otherwise you need a global (public) variable.

Comment: They're unrelated, I will have to go the global variable route.

Comment: I edited my answer.